# Zend Framework 2 - Add Form class

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-framework2

I just can't find the answer... Is there a way to pass a `CSS class` to my `open-form-tag`?

For example I want to create a form with the class ''form-horizontal''.

The docs say this:

```
// Render the opening tag
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
// <form action="/contact/process" method="post">
```

But how adding the form class name?

**Edit:** I tried adding this to my Form.php but nothing happend...

```
public function getOptions()
{
    return array('class' => 'form-horizontal');
}
```

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use

```
$this->setAttributes(array(
    'action' => '/someurl',
    'method' => 'post',
    'class'  => 'form-horizontal'
));
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright, the trick is to use `setAttribute` twice!

Do this in the Form.php:

```
$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$this->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');
```

Reference Link is:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html

Comment: Just as another hint: every occurance of `Attribute` in ZF2 should always reference to a HTML-Attribute. All other stuff is referenced to as `Option`

Answer (score 2):

It works is using

```
$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$this->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');
```